# If $a_n \uparrow a$, then $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (a_N - a_n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a -a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $a_n$ is a sequence increasing to $a > 0$. Apparently, the following is true:

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (a_N - a_n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a -a_n)$$

I am solving a problem and everything boiled down to proving the above equality. Can someone help me see this? (by hints or otherwise)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What can you throw at it? It's a direct consequence of the monotone convergence theorem for Lebesgue integrals. But quite possibly, Lebesgue integration is beyond the tool set you can currently use. Then one would need to do a bit more work.

Comment: @DanielFischer not really - I can readily use Lebesgue integration. Though wouldn't that be an overkill somehow? Anyway, how does one solve this using the monotone convergence theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can readily use Lebesgue integration: Let $\zeta$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, and for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ define $f_N(n) = (a_N - a_n)^+ = \max \{ a_N - a_n, 0\}$, and $f(n) = a-a_n$. Then $0 \leqslant f_N \uparrow f$, so by the monotone convergence theorem

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} (a_N - a_n) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} f_N\,d\zeta \uparrow \int_{\mathbb{N}} f\,d\zeta = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (a - a_n).$$

Without Lebesgue integration: It's clear that

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} (a_N - a_n)\leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (a - a_n),$$

and that the sequence of finite sums is monotonically increasing. So the limit of the finite sums exists, and is not larger than the infinite sum (which may be $+\infty$ or $< +\infty$, that doesn't matter). For every $K < \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (a - a_n)$, choose an $M$ such that

$$\sum_{n = 0}^M (a - a_n) > K.$$

Since $a_N \uparrow a$, we have

$$K < \sum_{n = 0}^M (a_N - a_n) \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} (a_N - a_n)$$

for all large enough $N$, so

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} (a_N - a_n) > K.$$

Comment: Can you please explain how the next-to-last inequation followed from $a_N \uparrow a$? (sorry - this is possibly a silly question but I am tired and I can't see things clearly at the moment)

Comment: Let $\varepsilon = \sum_{n = 0}^M (a - a_n) - K$. Then choose $N > M$ such that $a - a_N < \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}$. This yields $$\sum_{n = 0}^M (a_N - a_n) = \sum_{n = 0}^M (a - a_n) - (M+1)(a-a_N) = K + \varepsilon - (M+1)(a-a_N) > K.$$

Comment: I think we can simplify things here using the theorem that for any increasing monotone sequence it limit is the supremum (supposing the space is complete). At least this seems easier.